# Unpinning apps when using Gesture-based system navigation

Tags: miui, 8.1-oreo

I've recently acquired a Redmi Note 5, and I quite appreciate the gesture navigation. (Settings -> System & Device -> Full screen display -> Full screen gestures) However, I also like using app pinning when friends borrow my phones.

Traditionally, to unpin an app you have to hold Back and Overview at the same time. But in gesture mode, there is no navigation bar to press buttons in.

As it currently stands, I have to reboot the phone to unpin an app, which is impractical for various reasons.

Is there a way to unpin apps using gestures? (Or perhaps unpin with the fingerprint sensor or something like that, anything not involving the navigation bar. Or maybe even disabling gesture mode when an app is pinned)

Comment: Force-stopping the app or running `am task lock stop` works for unpinning any app. The problem is that I cannot use either of them without root access. As long as Android is rooted, you can use a Gesture control type app to setup a systemwide gesture, which when activated would kill the front-end app or run that command.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Huawei Mate 20 Pro, using gesture navigation, and I have found that to unpin an app you have to swipe from the side, as if you were going back, but hold it instead of releasing it. Then it will take you to the lock screen. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the suggestions. Sadly in MIUI long-hold the back swipe only causes it to behave like long-pressing Overview, which would erstwhile swap to the previous active app.